# Sharing an image with ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-file, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to share a downloaded bitmap via Android's ShareActionProvider, and I'm having an issue actually passing the bitmap to appropriate apps (such as Messenger, Google+, Gmail). When I pass the intent with the uri, nothing happens (image isn't populated in the 3rd party app).

Here is my Intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    writeToDirectory(bitmap, "cached-image.png"); // write bitmap to file system in order to share
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getFileUri("cached-image.png"))
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

I'm currently saving the bitmap to file using the following:

```
public String writeToDirectory(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
    assert context != null;
    assert bitmap != null;
    assert filename != null;

    // Ensure directory exists and create if not
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myApp";
    File f = new File(path);
    boolean dirExists = f.isDirectory();

    if (!f.isDirectory() && !f.exists()) {
        dirExists = f.mkdirs();
    }


    if (dirExists) {
        File file = new File(sharedPrivateExternalPath, filename);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            e(TAG, "Write failed!");
            e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and I'm retrieving the Uri with this method

```
public Uri getFileUri(String filename) {
    assert context != null;
    assert filename != null;

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myApp";
    File file = new File(path, filename);
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

I've checked that the file gets written to the appropriate place (Uri is `file:///storage/emulated/0/myApp/cached-image.png`) and was able to view the image there (did an `adb pull` from the device), though the image doesn't get passed. I don't see any errors in the log (no FileNotFoundException or anything of the sort). Is this a file permission issue? Am I not able to share to a "non-public" location?

<strike>If I change `getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myApp";` to plain `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` it works fine... but it's bothering me it doesn't work the other way :).</strike>

Any help would be great!

Comment: i don't get the problem  , you need to share the image path or what ?

Comment: Sorry, question was a little vague. I updated my question, but I also found my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had to do with code I didn't post (surprise, surprise). I was attempting to set the shareIntent in the `setOnShareTargetSelectedListener`... which apparently you can't do.

My problem was with this code snippet

```
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
            MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider, Intent intent) {
            String urlKey = mImageUrlList.get(mImageGallery.getCurrentItem()) + "\n";

            // This is the problem line
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getImageIntent(app.getImageCache().get(urlKey)));

            return false;
        }
    })
```